# Cannot download directory

Tags: wget

I am using wget to download the images which are contained [here](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/~marshall/imsim/raw/v85616257-fy.xfr/) but when i do this I just get the index file downloaded? How do I get the entire directory downloaded as a folder on my machine?
btw I use `wget -np -r URL` to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you should use the -m option, this way: `wget -m http://yourwebsite.com`.

I tried with your host and I see there's a robots.txt file that disallow wget to download.
So the right command for you should be the following: `wget -m -e robots=off http://yourwebsite.com`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but it doesnt seem to work .It still only creates a folder with the index page.I want it to go deep into the bottom of the hierarchy and fetch me the .tar.gz files.Any clue?

Comment: well i just tried downloading a single tar.gz by giving the direct link to it and it works fine.Could it have something to do with the (huge)size of the whole directory?

Comment: I made an edit to my previous answer as it's not wrong, it's just in your case that there's a need for one more option.